# Plane image gets smaller when in render view

Tags: image, uv-image-editor

When switching to render view my image plane gets shrunk in x axis. How can i keep original measurments from material view port?

http://g.recordit.co/jxtr81sqTT.gif

Comment: It appears to be an issue with your material. Could you add a screenshot of your material/node setup to your question? I think your texture is simply setup to not repeat, but I'm not sure what is causing the issue without seeing your setup.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP15O.jpg

Comment: Here is my node set up. Also ill add i am very noob when it comes to setting these up.

Comment: Just so you know you can edit your posts using the edit button at the bottom left as well as embed the images directly into your question via the add image button which can be found at the top. That's the preferred way of adding information to a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is the image texture node is set to clip, not repeat (fourth menu). This means that the image will not be repeated to fill up the rest of your UV map, since your UVs don't cover your entire texture (which is fine). It appears that the viewport automatically tiles the images, but the render will use the node settings.